# Trouble handling multiple assync requests in php

Tags: php, wordpress, asynchronous

I'm dealing with a webhook in another server, when this webhook is triggered my server recieves a POST request and then send a GET request for this other server. It all is being managed by php, the nature of webhooks implicates in multiple async http requests inside php, the problem is the other server has a rate limit of GET requests and if I blow it my ip got blocked for 3 minutes. I didn't like to make all of those requests full syncrhonous but to set a delay between their execution regardless regarding previous request was done or not. For example, minding in javascript, make a http request and then wait 2 seconds to make the next one regardless the return of promise. I'm working inside a wordpress environment and tried to create a lock structure like:

```
function web_hook_handler(){
    update_option('web_hook_locker', 'yes');// THE LOCKER,it's like to set a global variable which persists between scripts, it's from wordpress environment
    $prevent_infinite_loop = 0;//prevent infinite while if locker bugs
    while(true){
       if(get_option('web_hook_locker', 0) === 'no'){//locker was broken by a succefully async http request
         break;

        }

        sleep(1);//wait a oportunity to get locker broken
        $prevent_infinite_loop = $prevent_infinite_loop + 1;
        if ($prevent_infinite_loop >= 2){//while will last in maximum 2 seconds
           break;
         }


    }

    //some requests and data processing
    update_option('web_hook_locker', 'no')//breaking locker after http request
}
```

In my mind that function is meant to force each process wait 2 seconds before makes a http request or wait until the concurrent http request is done (it depends what one will last the least), can the execution of two requests be triggered so near so near to the point locker will not work?

Comment: Are you saying, that for _one_ incoming webhook request, you need to make _multiple_ GET requests - i.e., basically "keep trying", until that GET request gets a successful response? Because if not, and it is one incoming webhook request equals one outgoing GET request - I don't see how any forced delay is going to help?

Comment: I think a more robust solution would be to implement a queue system. When a webhook is received, add the request to a queue. Then, have a separate process (like a cron job) that periodically processes items in the queue, ensuring that there's a delay between each request.